# Finding common value in all strings in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings and want to find the value that is common in all of them.

For example:

```
["1234","1234A","1234ABC"]
```

I want to grab one value from this list that all string share. So in this case
I want to have `"1234"` since its the common value shared by all strings in the list.

How would I go about this in python?

Comment: Are looking for the "longest common substring"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Answer (score 0):

Incase this is NOT a problem of finding longest substring.
This will find common values for you

```
L = ["1234","1234A","1234ABC"]
S = []
for l in L:
    S.append(set(l))
intersect = S[0]
for s in S[1:]:
    intersect = intersect.intersection(s)
intersect
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one liner

```
os.path.commonprefix(["1234","1234A","1234ABC"])
```